# broadleaf commerce demo site login link gets redirected

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-security, broadleaf-commerce

I have configured Broadleaf demo site to run with tomcat server directly from eclipse (not by using ant task). I tried to visit login, register and cart page but the link got redirected. Since in demosite for tomcat, login page must be at /mycompany/login when i click on login link i get redirected to /mycompany/mycompany/login.

I tried to directly hit the url `http://localhost:8181/mycompany/login` but it also gets redirected/changed to `http://localhost:8181/mycompany/mycompany/login`. This same issue repeats on clicking register and cart link also.

In LoginController i can see request mapping as "@RequestMapping("/mycompany/login")".

In logs i can see "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mycompany/mycompany/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mycompany'" which is true as we do not have a mapping for this url.

Any pointer to where i can look for error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are actually seeing it redirect to `https://localhost:8081` (as opposed to **8181** and **http**).

Those URLs specifically are marked as requiring SSL in `applicationContext-security.xml`:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/register*" requires-channel="https" />
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/login*/**" requires-channel="https" />
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/account/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https" />
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/checkout/**" requires-channel="https" />
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/null-checkout/**" requires-channel="https" />
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/null-giftcard/**" requires-channel="https" />
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/confirmation/**" requires-channel="https" />
```

If you comment those out (or remove them) then you will no longer see redirects. The alternative is to just configure SSL on your Tomcat instance.

Furthermore, the `@RequestMapping` that you mentioned on `LoginController` should just be `@RequestMapping("/login")`. There is no need to include the `/mycompany` part of that (which I assume is the Tomcat context) since Spring URLs ignore it.

Comment: Voila!!! Thanks for the information. I got it working by removing requires-channel attribute. Will try configuring SSL Connector on tomcat as this is something new to me. Also not sure whether i would be allowed to configure SSL connector on web hosting server like mochahost !!!

Comment: i can confirm that i am not able to see `https://localhost:8081` but `http://localhost:8181`.

Comment: Hi : phillipuniverse could you help in this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077389/broadleaf-commerce-admin-controller-not-working